# Partition data unavailable until opened in files

Tags: partitioning, mount

I have one disk with all ubuntu partitions and a separate Data partition.

If i try to open a file located on Data partition through a program the file is unavailable.
If i open the partition in Files and then try to open the the same file through the same program everything works.

Is there something wrong with the mounting options and how do i best check that?

Comment: is it in your fstab ? 
`cat /etc/fstab` and check if your data partition is there somewhere

Comment: I am not sure I can help much but more information is needed. I'd suggest you add screen shots for your fstab file ('cat /etc/fstab'), 'lsblk' command, and 'sudo fdisk -l' command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the disk partitions other than root or swap are shown as available but not auto-mounted. Clicking on the partition icons in file manager runs `udisksctl` command in background that mounts those partitions for your user.

To make them auto-mounted , follow suggestions in [Automatically Mount Partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions) article from Ubuntu's official documentation site. Basically, you must have  additional entries in `/etc/fstab` file for any additional partition besides root or swap. Here's an example of an entry for my Windows partition

```
UUID=4EBAAE53BAAE36FD /media/WINDOWS  ntfs noatime,nodiratime,user=1000,rw 0 0
```

Use `sudo blkid` command in terminal to find out the UUID of each partition